# Why NUMBERVALUE ignores specified decimal separator?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I imported CSV and got this XLS sheet with a column "walking distance". I want to double check the value in the column "total distance". But just adding the "distance" columns together did not work for me. Problem is somehow my XLS does not understand the columns are using a dot as the decimal point/separator.

So I tried something simple first. Just convert the text/general column "walking distance" into a number column. See screenshot. But why did my Excel come up with the idea to convert "4835.8963" into "48358963.00"? See Column1.

[image]

Comment: what do you get with: `=--[@walkdistance]`

Comment: When using the Text to Columns Wizard, step 3 allows has the option to click for advanced. There you can define the thousands and Decimal separator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uK2ST.png